# Beamer Presentation with tiling image background using module \usebackgroundtemplate?

Tags: beamer, backgrounds

I am looking for a way so that Beamer Presentation will be tiling the image background using module `\usebackgroundtemplate`?

So far, this gives a background, but of course, it won't tile (mosaic like) the image.

It should be well widely portable (avoiding the cumbersome multido, which isn't installed on any tex installation!).

```
\documentclass[bigger]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%Global Background must be put in preamble
\usebackgroundtemplate{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{newton.jpg}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Introduction}
\begin{itemize}
\item 1
\item 2
\item 3
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Thank you

[image]

Comment: Can you please go back to your previous questions and look if the answers solve your problems and accept them, if they do?

Comment: Please consider the comment https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/398168/beamer-presentation-with-two-images-next-to-each-other-automatically-sized#comment990523_398168

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve a tiling effect by putting the image into a loop.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\usebackgroundtemplate{%
    \vbox{%
        \foreach\y in {1,...,5}{%
            \foreach\x in {1,...,5}{%
                \includegraphics[width=.2\paperwidth]{example-grid-100x100bp}%
            }%
            \linebreak
        }%
    }%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Introduction}
\begin{itemize}
\item 1
\item 2
\item 3
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```